# how to remove Recursion-Error in python tkinter?

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter, ttk

i am trying to build a calculator (initial stages) using tkinter-python 
when calling the run function of object its giving an **[RecursionError: maximum recursion depth exceeded]**
enable to find why and where it is calling the run function repeatedly

```
import tkinter as gui
from tkinter import ttk


class box(gui.Tk):

    def __init__(self):
        #op = operators()
        root = gui.Tk()
        root.title("Calculator")
        self.frame=ttk.Frame(root).grid()
        self.display=ttk.Entry(text='0',font=('Comic Sans MS',20))
        self.display.grid(row=0, columnspan=6)


        self.buttons()

    def buttons(self):
        #printing numbers
        self.seven=ttk.Button(text="7",command=lambda:self.getdata(7))
        self.seven.grid(row=1,column=0)

        self.eighth=ttk.Button(text="8",command=lambda:self.getdata(8))
        self.eighth.grid(row=1,column=1)

        self.nine=ttk.Button(text="9",command=lambda:self.getdata(9))
        self.nine.grid(row=1,column=2)

        self.four=ttk.Button(text="4",command=lambda:self.getdata(4))
        self.four.grid(row=2,column=0)

        self.five=ttk.Button(text="5",command=lambda:self.getdata(5))
        self.five.grid(row=2,column=1)

        self.six=ttk.Button(text="6",command=lambda:self.getdata(6))
        self.six.grid(row=2,column=2)

        self.one=ttk.Button(text="1",command=lambda:self.getdata(1))
        self.one.grid(row=3,column=0)

        self.two=ttk.Button(text="2",command=lambda:self.getdata(2))
        self.two.grid(row=3,column=1)

        self.three=ttk.Button(text="3",command=lambda:self.getdata(3))
        self.three.grid(row=3,column=2)


    def getdata(self,x):
        self.num=x



    def operate(self,y):
        #add code for operators
        self.getdata('op')

    def run(self):
        self.mainloop()

app=box()
app.run()
```

Comment: Can you post the full stack trace?

Comment: If your super class is `gui.Tk`, just call `super().__init__()` rather than `root = gui.Tk()` and change `root.title("Calculator")` to `self.title("Calculator")` and `self.frame=ttk.Frame(root).grid()` to`self.frame=ttk.Frame(self).grid()`. Otherwise, here `self.mainloop()` you're calling `Tk`'s `mainloop` method before its `__init__` method.

Comment: Incidentally, that's also where your problem lies and why you're getting a recursion error.

Comment: @Rashid 'Lee' Ibrahim the solution by Axe319 worked .unable to upload stack traceback as its saying mostly code and add some more info thanks though

Comment: @Axe319 that worked thanks